# Labview: a tab panel with vertical tabs

Tags: tabs, labview

How can I create a tab panel in labview with vertical tabs? I mean I know how to create a tab panel and when I set the location of the tabs to left, they are were I want them to be. But they are rotated and I want each name to be displayed horizontally:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest one option, which I am not sure is the best one.

You select tab location to left, tab size to fixed, hide tab names and write your tab names somewhere in FP and drag them where you want on your tab.

It would look like this. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it's the last resort. I would expect such an advanced language like Labview to have a simplest solution, an option that I can't find.

Comment: Believe me there is no simple one :) Anyway please post it, when you find one.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: LabVIEW does not allow horizonally align text on left aligned tabs for tab controls however...

Change the Tab Layout to an image instead of text and import your text that way (as an image). This way the text will pop-in and pop-out when the page is selected and the image will be part of the tab control instead of some floating object.

Right click the tab control and go to Advanced>>Tab Layout>>Image. You'll need to use Ctrl-C in from an image editing application (MSpaint works fine for this) in order to import the image from the clipboard to the tab control

[image]

Comment: I think because it is a duplicate of the above solution

Comment: The answers are not the same. Khachick is suggesting the use of free labels that A) Block mouse down events which won't let the tab actual change pages and B) Do not animate with the changing of pages. I am suggesting the use of a built in control feature which satifies both A and B. Regardless, I agree LabVIEW is lacking in a vertical text option.

Comment: I modified the voting.